# Biopython: How to get the compound name of the pdb file of a protein?

Tags: biopython

Ive been trying to solve it with the following term:

structure.header['compound']

But all I get is the molecules id instead of its name!

Comment: Do you mean the name of the protein structure or the name of compound/ligand?

Comment: i mean the name of the compound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the name of crystal structure, i.e. the name which is shown at the PDB site, you can use:

```
print(structure.header['name'])
```

e.g. (assuming you have `1iah.pdb` in your current working directory)

```
from Bio.PDB import *
parser = PDBParser()
structure = parser.get_structure('1IAH', '1iah.pdb')
print(structure.header['name'])
```

will give you

> ' crystal structure of the atypical protein kinase domain of a trp
>   ca-channel, chak (adp-mg complex)'

which is identical to the name shown here: http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=1IAH

---

**Update in response to the comments**

In order to get the name of the compound one can use:

```
print(structure.header['compound']['1']['molecule'])
```

Comment: i dont want the name of the protein but of the compound. in the previous case it would be:

Comment: COMPND    MOL_ID: 1;                                                            
COMPND   2 MOLECULE: TRANSIENT RECEPTOR POTENTIAL-RELATED PROTEIN;              
COMPND   3 CHAIN: A, B;                                                         
COMPND   4 FRAGMENT: PROTEIN KINASE DOMAIN, RESIDUES 1549-1828;                 
COMPND   5 SYNONYM: TRP-RELATED;                                                
COMPND   6 EC: 2.7.1.37;                                                        
COMPND   7 ENGINEERED: YES

Comment: Do you mean `TRANSIENT RECEPTOR POTENTIAL-RELATED PROTEIN`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably here is an answer:
http://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ

```
keywords = structure.header['keywords']
```

> The available keys are **name**, head, deposition_date, release_date,
>   structure_method, resolution, structure_reference (maps to a list of
>   references), journal_reference, author and compound (maps to a
>   dictionary with various information about the crystallized compound).